# Instanciate proxy of WCF service referring to the same instanciating class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

I have a class implementing some audit methods (AuditcClass.cs). I have also implemented a WCF service that uses the AuditcClass.dll methods.

Now I need to be able also to reference the WCF service from within the AuditcClass. However I cannot simply use the generated proxies to reference it, since there are several conflicts with namespaces.

As first approach, I encapsulated the proxy within another namespace, solving many conflicts, but still introducing new ones with other general classes (as example, Exceptions namespace).

Is there an approach by which I could reference the web service within the class, even if the service uses the same class' methods and enums?

Comment: I feel your design is not correct, as it introduces some kine of circular dependencies. This may be solved using some patterns, like IoC or dependency injection. Maybe you may describe a bit more your classes, with dependences beetween them.

Comment: @Steve B: prefeclty right. The scenario: I provide a DLL for auditing. It invokes stored procedures to store the items in a DB. Now we need to provide the possibility to invoke a WCF service, in order to store indirectly the item into the DB (via the service). The service itself, references the aufit DLL since it needs to expose/execute the same audit methods. I agree with you that there is a sort of reference loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by using the parameter `/reference:<file path>` of the [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool:
 `References types in the specified assembly. When generating clients, use this option to specify assemblies that might contain types that represent the metadata being imported.`

This allowed me to exclude from the generated proxy the shared dlls avoiding reference conflicts.